# JavaEE JPA returning versions of old data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

We are building a REST application using JPA which we have trouble getting to work properly.

The issue is that when doing updates or adding items jpa selects starts returning multiple versions of the changed. For example if Item contains A and is changed to B then changed to C, select queries will return A first run, B second, C third, A fourth etc. Sometimes it wont show directly but holding down f5 on the browser for GET items resource then changing the data always generates this problem.

Ive created a clean sample project which demonstrates this. We use Glassfish 4.1.0 (since there were som other issues with 4.1.1).

1. Created mysql database 'testdb' Created a table 'item' containing two VARCHAR(45) fields, 'firstName' and 'lastName'.
2. Created a new maven project based on 'javaee7-essentials-acrhetype'. (https://github.com/AdamBien/javaee7-essentials-archetype)
3. Added datasource in intellij and generated an Entity bean for this Item entity. Adjusted persistence.xml to include username and password.
4. Created a simple DTO / Pojo class to receive the PUT data.
5. Created an ItemResource class.

All in all 4 classes and persistence.xml + pom.xml

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>testdb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>testdb</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="LocalUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>test.server.entities.ItemEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="abc123" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

ItemDTO

```
public class ItemDTO {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

ItemEntity bean (added the namedqueries manually)

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Item.All", query = "SELECT item from ItemEntity item"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Item.Get", query = "SELECT item from ItemEntity item WHERE item.id = :id")
})
@Table(name = "item", schema = "testdb", catalog = "")
public class ItemEntity {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ItemEntity that = (ItemEntity) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
        if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) return false;
        if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

ItemResources class

```
@Path("items")
public class ItemResources {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public ItemResources() {
        if(emf == null) {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LocalUnit");
        }
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllAccounts() {
        EntityManager manager = getEntityManager();
        Collection<ItemEntity> accounts = null;
        try {
            accounts = manager.createNamedQuery("Item.All").getResultList();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
        return Response.ok().entity(new GenericEntity<Collection<ItemEntity>>(accounts) {}).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response updateAccount(@PathParam("id") int id, ItemDTO itemDTO) {
        EntityManager manager = getEntityManager();
        try {
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            TypedQuery<ItemEntity> query = manager.createNamedQuery("Item.Get", ItemEntity.class);
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            ItemEntity account = query.getSingleResult();
            account.setFirstName(itemDTO.getFirstName());
            account.setLastName(itemDTO.getLastName());
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            manager.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }

        return Response.ok().entity("OK").build();
    }
}
```

And the main application class (no web.xml, empty beans.xml)

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

}
```

Summarized this dont work. The problem described in the beginning occurs which makes it impossible to use for anything real. Are we missing something here, shouldnt this simple example work?

We have a real application containing this issue and we have some time trying to find out why it behaves like this. We tried different ways of clearing the cache, evicting the factory, tried changing connection isolation, disabling 2ndlevel and query cache in persistence.xml but still got the same issuein the end or traded for more severe db issues. Tried on two different servers running same glassfish versions. So we are at the point if we have to roll back to pure jdbc/sql to get this working.

HOWEVER strangely i have not yet been able to reproduce the issue when deploying in intellij yet. But when deploying the .war file on any server weve tried so far the issue appears. But when officially depolyed it seems the only way to make it work would be to create a new fctory instance for each request then close it when done. Which seems extremely wasteful.

If anyone could help us solve this and thus avoid alot of refactoring we would be forever greatful :) Are we missing something vital that is needed for this to work?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? For instance, what does hibernate's SQL log say?

Comment: Running on real server, is there more than 1 server or some caching layer in front? Or some sort of eventual consistent distributed sql I've never heard of?

Comment: It has been tested on 2 different simple windows servers, on old, on new, no cluster, cloud, cache etc. Just plain windows server and glassfish 4.1.0. There is a downgraded version of jackson on it (was needed for swagger to work) but otherwise stock. I will do another testrun on different version of glasfish just to compare.  

We have checked glassfish logs earlier but i will see if i can dig anything useful up in regards to hibernate, will get back on that asap.

Comment: I searched the serverlogs but found nothing that looked suspicious. Started looking up getting more detailed log data. But i tried scrapping the persistence unit and set up a jta datasource instead and all issues just dissapeared. So im putting this to rest at the moment but if anyone has similar issues, jta saves so many headaches..